# 2021.3.33f1 Unity2D TopDown Pixel Sprite Art: Animations create a snapping effect between loops, how do I smooth out the loops?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, animation

I am using the new animation system with a controller. My animation has 6 keyframes and looks good and smooth when animated in Aseprite. The animation clip's loop is not smooth and has a snapping effect between starting and stopping.

The primary concern was the snapping issue in the animations, however when I tried to find a solution I discovered I am also missing animation curves (the curves tab shows up next to dopesheet but basically does nothing and has no keyframes on it) and when I right click a keyframe in the dopesheet it only shows add key and delete key, and the add key button is greyed out. Also, the keyframes in the dopesheet are not connecting by a line or curve, in case they are supposed to be. I can't find anyone mentioning an issue like this anywhere.

One "solution" I found was to use the loop pose option for the animation clip, however this had no effect on anything as far as I could tell.

Comment: It's a bit hard to imagine what exactly you are looking at .. could you include some screenshots in your question and maybe even add a screen video of the issue behavior

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.